# Fast way to md5 each element of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, hash, md5

I am woring with a numpy's 1d array with thousands of uint64 numbers in python 2.7. What is the fastest way to calculate the md5 of every number individually?

Each number has to be converted to string before calling the md5 function. I read in many places that iterating over numpy's arrays and doing stuff in pure python is dead slow. Is there any way to circumvent that?

Comment: what's the point of this conversion? how md5 string can be used, that the original float64 can not?

Comment: I just want to convert the uint64 to strings and then get their MD5 as fast as possible. Gonna use those md5 strings later on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @lenik is right and that you don't *need* this conversion. Converting before applying the MD5 seems to be an attempt of optimizing a code that is not even yet functional. Would you have a try applying lenik's suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write a wrapper for OpenSSL's `MD5()` function that accepts NumPy arrays. Our baseline will be a pure Python implementation.

Create a builder

```
# build.py
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()

header = r"""
void md5_array(uint64_t* buffer, int len, unsigned char* out);
"""

source = r"""
#include <stdint.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

void md5_array(uint64_t * buffer, int len, unsigned char * out) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        MD5((const unsigned char *) &buffer[i], 8, out + i*16);
    }
}
"""

ffi.set_source("_md5", source, libraries=['ssl'])
ffi.cdef(header)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffi.compile()
```

and a wrapper

```
# md5.py
import numpy as np
import _md5

def md5_array(data):
    out = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype='|S16')

    _md5.lib.md5_array(
        _md5.ffi.from_buffer(data),
        data.size,
        _md5.ffi.cast("unsigned char *", _md5.ffi.from_buffer(out))
    )
    return out
```

and a script compare the two:

```
# run.py
import numpy as np
import hashlib
import md5

data = np.arange(16, dtype=np.uint64)
out = [hashlib.md5(i).digest() for i in data]
out2 = md5.md5_array(data)

print(data)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
print(out)
# [b'}\xea6+?\xac\x8e\x00\x95jIR\xa3\xd4\xf4t', ... , b'w)\r\xf2^\x84\x11w\xbb\xa1\x94\xc1\x8c8XS']
print(out2)
# [b'}\xea6+?\xac\x8e\x00\x95jIR\xa3\xd4\xf4t', ... , b'w)\r\xf2^\x84\x11w\xbb\xa1\x94\xc1\x8c8XS']

print(all(out == out2))
# True
```

To compile the bindings and run the script, run

```
python build.py
python run.py
```

For large arrays it's about 15x faster (I am a bit disappointed by that honestly...)

```
data = np.arange(100000, dtype=np.uint64)

%timeit [hashlib.md5(i).digest() for i in data]
169 ms ± 3.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit md5.md5_array(data)
12.1 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If you want to put the bindings in a library and compile them at install time, put the following in your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    setup_requires=["cffi>=1.0.0"],
    cffi_modules=["package/build.py:ffi"],
    install_requires=["cffi>=1.0.0"],
)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module '_md5' has no attribute 'lib', why?

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe your cffi version is very old or you have a `_md5.py` file in that directory.

Comment: I also experienced the AttributeError: module '_md5' has no attribute 'lib' problem and I'm running `cffi` version `0.14.5` (released after this was posted if I'm not mistaken), so I would say it is not an old version problem...anyone managed to make fix the 'no lib' problem?
Cheers :)

Comment: @LucaClissa You probably forgot to build the bindings. I have adjusted the answer to be more explicit about it.

Comment: I apologize in advance for the (possibly) silly answer: I run build.py and run.py code within the same interactive session and I can see three *_md5*-related files in the folder (`_md5.c`, `_md5.o` and `_md5.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`). Is that what you meant by build the bindings?

Comment: Yes. These files are the output of CFF after running `build.py`

Comment: This seems to be an excellent solution for a quite common problem, but having to build the `_md5` bindings beforehand is not ideal. I wonder if there is any library out there that already does this at install time

Comment: [CFFI can do this at install time](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html), if you set it up correctly. Essentially you'll have to add a `cffi_modules` key to your `setup.py`.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend to avoid converting `uint64` to strings. You may use `struct` to get the binary data that can be subsequently fed to the `hashlib.md5()`:

```
>>> import struct, hashlib
>>> a = struct.pack( '<Q', 0x423423423423 )
>>> a
'#4B#4B\x00\x00'
>>> hashlib.md5( a ).hexdigest()
'de0fc624a1b287881eee581ed83500d1'
>>>
```

This would definitely will speed up the process, since there's no conversion, just simple byte copies.

Also, gettig `hexdigest()` may be replaced with `digest()`, that returns the binary data, which is faster that converting that to hex string. Depending on how you're planning to use that data later, this might be a good approach.

Comment: That's the MD5 of the entire array, no? OP wants to calculate the MD5 of each element individually.

Comment: Ah, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

**ATTENTION!** Sorry, I missed the question. The code below calculates MD5 of the whole array and without any conversion. This was put into a wrong place.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype="uint64")
>>> m = hashlib.md5(arr.astype("uint8"))
>>> m.hexdigest()
'7cfdd07889b3295d6a550914ab35e068'
```

Comment: It looks like this gets the md5 of the whole array, not each element

Comment: The question's title was misleading, I have just updated it to reflect the real question. However, this response is exactly what I have been looking for: md5 a numpy array.